# Merge string with current date in chart title

Tags: c#

I am trying to put date of current day in title of my chart.

The code that make the title is:

```
 Title title = Chart1.Titles.Add("Chart of day: HERE I WANT TO PUT THE CURRENT DATE");
```

I want replace "HERE I WANT TO PUT THE CURRENT DATE" for current date.

Comment: please be more specific which control are you using, which technology, do you want to concatenate a datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate it like:

```
Title title = Chart1.Titles.Add("Chart of day: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MM yyyy"));
```

With c# 6.0 you can use interolated strings:

```
Title title = Chart1.Titles.Add($"Chart of day: {DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MM yyyy")}");
```

which is more nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current datetime with `DateTime.Now` and then just format your string.

```
Title title = Chart1.Titles.Add($"Chart of day: {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
```

If you just want the date component then you can use `DateTime.Now.Date`

See documentation for [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
Title title = Chart1.Titles.Add($"Chart of day: {DateTime.Today.ToString("D")}");
```

Replace the `D` with an appropriate format string, as needed: [See available strings here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)